# MYSQL IN clause only returning results from first value combination

Tags: mysql, clause

I have used this query before:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stone_list 
WHERE type IN ('ALEXANDRITE','AMETHYST') 
   AND shape IN ('OVAL') ORDER BY type, shape
```

It worked for me in the past, only this time it does something very weird. When I have only one value for the shape `IN`, the query only returns results where type is `ALEXANDRITE` and shape is `OVAL`, even though there are rows where `type = AMETHYST and shape = OVAL` as well.

Now, when I add a second shape, e.g. `shape IN ('OVAL','ROUND')`, it will return values for both `type = ALEXANDRITE and type = AMETHYST` and for `shape = OVAL and shape = ROUND` (so, it works as expected).

Really trumps me.

Anyone with any ideas?

THANKS!

Comment: If you change the order in your `IN` clause i.e. `type in ('AMETHYST', 'ALEXANDRITE')` does it only return `type AMETHYST and shape = OVAL`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. NiftyDude: It still returns only Alexandrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the query, so I can only assume that there is something you've overlooked or omitted from the question.

```
mysql> select * from stone_list;
+----+-------------+--------+
| id | type        | shape  |
+----+-------------+--------+
|  1 | ALEXANDRITE | OVAL   |
|  2 | ALEXANDRITE | ROUND  |
|  3 | BASILIC     | OVAL   |
|  4 | AMETHYST    | SQUARE |
|  5 | AMETHYST    | ROUND  |
|  6 | AMETHYST    | OVAL   |
+----+-------------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT * FROM stone_list WHERE type IN ('ALEXANDRITE','AMETHYST') AND shape IN ('OVAL') ORDER BY type, shape
    -> ;
+----+-------------+-------+
| id | type        | shape |
+----+-------------+-------+
|  1 | ALEXANDRITE | OVAL  |
|  6 | AMETHYST    | OVAL  |
+----+-------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> describe stone_list;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| type  | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| shape | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. NiftyDude: It still returns only Alexandrite.

Comment: Gview, I am perplexed by the error. It is a very simple query and as I said I have used it in the past. I have no idea why it wouldn't work. I am obviously overlooking something.

Comment: One possibility is that the data doesn't match what you expect.  For example a typo could be at issue, either in the query constants or the data in the type or shape columns.  One other possibility is that the data has some spaces before or after the value, causing the query not to match.

Comment: gview, thanks for taking the time to answer. The query was fine. Had a mistake in the php that outputs the results. Silly me. Thanks again for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

You're not grouping by anything this is equivalent to keeping one row!
You need to use "group by"

...

group by type, shape

Comment: Please expand your answer by giving the full corrected solution here.  You can also cite a reference on "group by"